# the difference between a real and virtual method in c++

Tags: c++

i have read this definations on wikipedia but i want to understand in them in simple in english these are the definations i read on wikipedia

A `virtual function` or `virtual method` is a `function` or `method` whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature"

"A `pure virtual function` or `pure virtual method` is a `virtual function` that is required to be implemented by a derived class that is not abstract"

my other question is how can one execute a `virtual method` in `class A` or only in `class B` if i have `class A` and `class B`....i have read many books and i know people with say this is a possible duplicated to some questions here but i really want to understand in simple english because that how i get to know things easily and faster.

Comment: What part of the definition don't you understand? Is it the word "overridden" or is it something else?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=388ebf8adc9b8126135d3e5556ad6d19

Comment: You cannot execute methods on classes, unless they are static methods. You always need an object on which the method would be executed - either directly or through a pointer/reference.

Comment: To be clear, there's nothing wrong about asking for a "simple English" explanation, but you need to tell us what exactly you don't understand. What is confusing you with regards to `virtual` functions? We're not going to go and define each and every word in the definition for `virtual` functions.

Comment: @Joni ya i think the overidden part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-virtual method of a base class cannot be overridden by subclasses that inherit from it. (Note that this is different from "redefining" the method in a subclass)

A virtual method of a base class can be overridden by subclasses. (See @juanchopanza's comment about `private` visibility)

A pure virtual method in a base class means that it is an "abstraction" (think of it as an interface only) - as in it's not supposed to be used directly as is, but rather the base class expects subclasses to override the method to give an actual implementation.

Comment: A private virtual method can also be overriden by a derived class. This is an important component of template method pattern implementations in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza isn't that redefining? If it's private, I'm not sure how the derived class would have visibility to it - could you explain a bit more or point me to some reading?

Comment: Nope, it is overriding. Try it out!